# php exec not executing if called from browser

Tags: permissions, exec, php

This is a recurring topic in stackoverflow, but finally I couldn't find any clear solution.

**I'VE THIS PHP SCRIPT ON MY LOCAL XAMPP (OS X)**

**test.php**

```
<?php exec('lpr -MyPrinter photos/image.jpg'); ?>
```

**IT WORKS IF I CALL IT FROM TERMINAL**

```
kurt$ php test.php
```

**BUT IT DOES NOT WORK IF I CALL IT FROM BROWSER**

```
http://localhost/mysite/test.php
```

Consider that my security requirements are very low, because I'll use this script locally only for personal purposes. Can you address me to the right solution?

Comment: bet its i user permission issue, but dont know how os x does such things

Comment: Adding to @Dagon's comment, check the user and group that your script is running as when executed by your server.  I'm also not exactly sure how users/groups/permissions are handled on OSX, but your server is probably executing the scripts as a user created specifically for the server, which will have restricted permissions.

Comment: @G-Nugget whoami returns "nobody" when called from browser

Comment: Also not sure about osx, but quite often php cli (command line interface) has a different php.ini. It is possible that the cli php.ini has exec enabled, while the web php.ini has not.

Answer (score 2):

Could have any number of reasons, but I suggest to look at the error message. The `exec()` function will not return it, but you can redirect error output to a temporary file:

```
<?php exec('lpr -MyPrinter photos/image.jpg 2> /tmp/error.txt'); ?>
```

Look into /tmp/error.txt after calling the script in the browser.