# unable to catch svn command output using exec function

Tags: php, svn, diff, working-copy

I tried to check status of a file in svn working copy by issuing following commmand:

```
svn status /home/guna/server/local/svndump/site/head.php
```

Which outputs results like,

```
M       /home/guna/server/local/svndump/site/head.php
```

But when i tried through the same command in php i got empty array as result,

```
<?php
exec('svn status /home/guna/server/local/svndump/site/head.php',$re);
echo "<pre>";print_r($re);echo '</pre>';
?>
```

What is the issue here? can somebody help me. Answers appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found solution. I checked for errors while using exec function by doing this:

```
exec('svn status /home/guna/server/local/svndump/site/head.php 2> /tmp/err.txt);
```

Then i checked the error log and found following error:
"/usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1: version `GCC_4.2.0' not found (required by /usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6)"

So i copied **libgcc_s.so.1** from `/usr/lib/` directory to `/opt/lampp/lib/` , issue solved.

Following two discussions helped me:
[error not showing in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295292/php-exec-not-executing-if-called-from-browser) and 
[library error](http://linux42.org/kb/%27GCC_4.2.0%27+not+found.../?kbid=456)